# Is JPA persistence.xml classpath located?

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven-2, jpa, classpath

Here's what I'm trying to do.  I'm using JPA persistence in a web application, but I have a set of unit tests that I want to run outside of a container.

I have my primary `persistence.xml` in the `META_INF` folder of my main app and it works great in the container (Glassfish).

I placed a second `persistence.xml` in the `META-INF` folder of my `test-classes` directory.  This contains a separate persistence unit that I want to use for test only.  In eclipse, I placed this folder higher in the classpath than the default folder and it seems to work.

Now when I run the maven build directly from the command line and it attempts to run the unit tests, the `persistence.xml` override is ignored.  I can see the override in the `META-INF` folder of the maven generated `test-classes` directory and I expected the maven tests to use this file, but it isn't.  My Spring test configuration overrides, achieved in a similar fashion are working.

I'm confused at to whether the `persistence.xml` is located through the classpath.  If it were, my override should work like the spring override since the maven surefire plugin [explains](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#testClassesDirectory) "[The test class directory] will be included at the beginning the test classpath".

Did I wrongly anticipate how the `persistence.xml` file is located?

I could (and have) create a second persistence unit in the production `persistence.xml` file, but it feels dirty to place test configuration into this production file.  Any other ideas on how to achieve my goal is welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`persistence.xml` is loaded from the classpath; in the past, I've done exactly what you described.

It's most likely an issue with maven. You can debug the maven classpath by running it with the `-X` option.

Comment: OK - Thanks for the feedback.  At least I know I'm not doing something that's totally out there.

Comment: OK - this is working now.  Before I had named each persistence unit in the different files with the same name.  I changed the test persistence unit to have a different name.  It doesn't seem right to me, but maybe this is a limitation I didn't know about.

Comment: I went and dug up the code where I had done this before, and I did have a different persistence unit defined for unit tests, although my test persistence.xml file did have the same (non-test) persistence unit also defined. It probably wasn't necessary though. I think the unit tests use the test persistence unit when creating the entity manager.

Answer (score 4):

It is unclear where you placed the "second" `persistence.xml` (the test version) but you should place it in `src/test/resources/META-INF`. Test resources are automatically added to the classpath set up by Maven for your unit tests and take precedence over resources placed in `src/main/resources`.